# No exe file created after installing spyder 2.2.1

Tags: failed-installation, spyder

Just finished installing spyder 2.2.1, but i got no .exe file. I only have .bat file. running the .bat does start spyder, but the lack of .exe makes me think the installation process went wrong somewhere.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) No, there is no problem at all. Spyder is not built as an executable in Windows because it's based on Python too (which is an interpreted, not a compiled language).

*Note*: By the way, Spyder 2.1 is too old (and now unmaintained). Please refer to our [downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/downloads/list) to install the most recent version (which right now is 2.2.1).

Comment: Yes, this is what i installed. 2.2.1. so you are saying that to run spyder i need to run the batch file? So how can i make a desktop shortcut to spyder? I remember that in the last version i did have an exe and an icon too...

Comment: Yes, you need to run the .bat file. This is currently a limitation of our installation process that we plan to fix in 2.3. I think you can right-click on the bat file and create a shortcut on your desktop to start it more quickly.

Comment: Oh goodie, SO has the question :-). My biggest problem with Spyder not being an executable is that I can't pin it to the taskbar (the pinned program is just the Python interpreter, not Spyder). This would really be a very nice thing to fix in a next version!

Comment: I see. I'm no Windows expert (cause I work on Linux and Mac) but I'll see what I can do about it for our next release.

Comment: Is this still an issue? My Spyder folder has no executable file, so I can't even assign `.py` files to open in Spyder **in any way**. That's quite annoying in 2021. (Brings me crazy and I'm already looking for some other IDE just because of this.)